# Detect/Disable Screen Recording on Cordova iOS app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

We developed Cordova app using ionic framework and we want to prevent screen recording. We used this plugin for iOS app but it doesn't work.

```
<plugin name="https://github.com/twogate/cordova-plugin-detect-screen-recording.git"/>
```

Here are the events:

**isCaptured**

```
window.onCaptureStatusChanged.isCaptured(function(isCaptured) {
    console.log(isCaptured);
});
```

**onCaptureStatusChanged**

```
window.onCaptureStatusChanged.onCaptureStatusChanged(function(isCaptured) {
    console.log(isCaptured);
});
```

There is no response from these events when we start recording.

Anybody please help. Thanks in Advance!